# Avoiding developper's bad Optimisation intuition

Tags: java, performance

I saw on a article this statement:

> Developers love to optimize code and with good reason. It is so
>   satisfying and fun. But knowing when to optimize is far more
>   important. Unfortunately, developers generally have horrible intuition
>   about where the performance problems in an application will actually
>   be.

Im looking for how can a developper avoid that bad intuition, is there some realy good tools to find which parts of your code realy need optimization  (for java) , and if you now of some articles, tips or good reads on this subject.

thanks .

Comment: lookup 'code profilers' for a plethora of information about this subject

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing is to have a global vision of the system that is being implemented. A lot of premature optimization occurs when programmers look at the problem from a narrow perspective. For example, implementing security in specific areas instead of building security as a global concern for the application. So stress needs to be in program design than just plain coding. Peer programming with right candidates can help improve this situation.

As far as tools go,
We had used the built-in Netbeans profiler and that was very useful in finding classes that needs to be re-visited in terms of performance/optimization.
An excellent example that helped us is [here](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/javaee/ecommerce/test-profile.html)

Comment: whoever down-voted, why?

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I would do is to make it a rule to avoid premature optimization. I would then be looking at getting a profiler like one of the ones here: http://java-source.net/open-source/profilers and attaching that to the app. This will tell you what should and should not be optimized.